# Word for "a group of people responding in unison to a greeting"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word to describe the event in which a group of people respond in unison to a greeting or introduction.

The most obvious example I can think of is in an Alcoholics Anonymous meeting, when a person introduces themselves and the rest of the group responds in unison with the same phrase.

Another example might be a customer entering a restaurant and the employees all greet the customer with the same saying.

The best word I could use to describe this is a "reprise", but I don't think it's commonly used this way.

**Edit:** An example of a sentence of how I would expect this word to be used might be:

> John expected a *reprise* after introducing himself to the group for the first time, but all he got were stares and murmurs.

Comment: There is some element of  "call and response" there too ...   which might really be a better way of describing the situation as a whole if people "in the chorus" (good answer below) are responding to a prompt.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_and_response  It might not always be right to call a group of people in the room a 'chorus' because it sort of implies some levels of obedience/formal role to the director in a way 'participants' or  'members' would not

Comment: Please provide a sentence showing how you're imagining the word would be used.

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: I think 'warm reception' would be used here most of the time. I'd consider a situation where 'the group responds in unison with the same phrase' to someone they're meeting for the first time off-putting to positively scary,  a mantra.

Answer (score 6):

*[Chorus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chorus)* can be used to refer to a group of people saying something in unison

Example:
"Hi everybody!" said Dr.Nick,
"Hi Dr. Nick!" the crowd responded in chorus

Comment: I like the sound of Dr. Nick.

Comment: I like this answer as written "crowd responded in chorus"  ...   OP should be aware that refering to a group as a 'chorus' can be dicey if not done right ... it could imply more allegiance to a leader, not only cooperation or agreement on an issue.   If used wrong it can veer into "preaching to the choir" sort of stuff.

Comment: @Tom22 - for OP's purpose I wouldn't worry too much about this.  Example: *The cheerful chorus that always responded to his opening self-identification as an alcoholic never failed to relax and galvanize him, and kickstart his group confessional.* My point is that the context will limit its applicability sufficiently in most cases.

Comment: An alternative phrasing would be "'Hi Dr. Nick' the crowd chorused"

Comment: @aparente001  yeah, I suppose it really would be very few situations where the connotation of support chorus lends would not apply to saying something in unison.  Even a chorus of 'boos' would mean that the chorus was united in their efforts in the support of a contrary idea .  I mean, lol, I guess you'd never reply 'in unison' without some sort of  'congregationality' (is that a word ? )  even at a Rolling Stones concert

Comment: @Tom22 - I'm glad you're feeling better.  Me, I'm hoping to avoid as many choruses of boos as possible during my remaining years....

Answer (score -2):

unilateral or unified. or IN unison. otherwise...systematically. comprehensively , also

'the crowd systematically responded'. 'the crowd collectively replied/responded' 'the crowd responded regimentary'   i would gree with 'the  crowd responded in chorus' BUT, chorus , is of reference to tone/pitch etc. SAME CHORD. originally anyway. lol

Comment: None of these are nouns.

Comment: they certainly are my friend. 'collectively' . there you go. in any warped version of REAL english. OR non real. .... QUOTE-The Quick Answer
What are nouns?

A noun is a "naming" word.

A noun is a word for a person, place, or thing. Everything we can see or talk about is represented by a word that names it. That "naming" word is called a noun.

Comment: dont get confused with proper nouns and 'so called' common nouns. No such thing as a common noun. It is simple a noun

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to say, but these suggestions are pretty much all categorically adjectives - naming an attribute of a person, place or thing - and not naming the actual person, place or thing as a noun would.